# Similar function like getScriptPath from ZF1 in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm currently mapping my ZF1 applications to ZF2 and was wondering if there is a similar function like `$this->view->getScriptPath()` from ZF1 in ZF2? I spend already my half day, but didn't find a good solution. It would also be fine to get at least the **basePath** of the **Module** or the **template folder of the Module**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the follow-up questions, what you are really looking for is the path to a given template file. This is actually relatively easy, assuming you're using the default PhpRenderer: you grab the resolver, and resolve the path.

If you're inside a view script already, the following should work:

```
$path = $this->resolver($templateName);
```

If you're elsewhere, you need access to either the PhpRenderer, or the ViewResolver. If you have access to the service manager, pull the ViewResolver service, and call resolve() on it:

```
$resolver = $services->get('ViewResolver');
$path     = $resolver->resolve($templateName);
```

This is superior to knowing where the module lives, as the developer may have chosen to override the template within the application; the resolver will know where even the new location is.

Comment: I suppose this only works if I setup the path in the configuration before.

Comment: I'm looking to retrieve the path to the template folder where the templates are stored for this particular controller, not to a template file. This is what `getScriptPath` did in ZF1.

Comment: Matthias -- ZF2 operates differently. Resolvers take care of this at this time, and the assumption in ZF2 is that the templates could reside anywhere -- considering that an application consists of many modules, and some may be overriding others, the idea of a canonical script path for a given module doesn't make sense. As such, you can resolve the path of individual templates only.